# Upload multiple files (with multiple attr) in custom form: how to get files?

Tags: forms, files

I've made a form. Now I want it to upload files. I've made a form element to do that:

```
  $form['attachments'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Attachments'),
    '#name' => 'attachments[]',
    '#attributes' => array('multiple' => ''),
  );
```

I've set `#name` and `#attributes.multiple` because I want to use the HTML5 multiple files upload thingie. They invented that for a very good reason. I assume Drupal knows how to handle that.

How do I get the files in the submit handler? I don't want to save them to the file system. I want to e-mail them.

Ofcourse (?) I can just query `$_FILES`, but even I think that's not right in a framework like Drupal.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think [form api file element type][1] supports that as of now, there is a html5 core initiative for D8 and hopefully we will see it change in D8. For now, you can try [plupload element type][2] (Abandoned project :( ) which uses the plupload js library by default, maybe you can take your hint from this module.


  [1]: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#file
  [2]: http://drupal.org/project/plupload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried [HTML5 Upload](http://drupal.org/sandbox/z7/1348240) yet, but it might help you out.

Comment: That's only for managed files. And only in entity forms. Close enough though. And very relevant to my new project.